# rewrite rule 404 not found

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

why in the bandidos wont this work? 404 not found

```
RewriteRule ^threads/cats/([0-9]+)$ /forum/cats.php?id=$1
```

apache error log:

```
[Thu Jan 20 20:18:18 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/threads
[Thu Jan 20 20:18:18 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 1):

Try prefixing it with a `/` and add an `?` just incase it's not necessary.

```
RewriteRule ^/?threads/cats/([0-9]+)$ /forum/cats.php?id=$1
```

Comment: You actually saved me from this bug, I don't know why he didn't accept your answer